# How to get first record in each grouped array using typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an array, what I have to do is I need to group by and need to get the first element in each group to an array. I managed to do the grouping part and struggling to do the second part can someone pls help me to do this.

Below is what I tried,

```
  this.faresDataAirlineGroup = this.faresData.reduce(function (r, a) {
  r[a.AirCode] = r[a.AirCode] || [];
  r[a.AirCode].push(a);

  return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

sample Json,

```
[
{
"RfNo": "500",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "AF"
},
{
"RfNo": "502",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "DD"
},
{
"RfNo": "501",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "DD"
},
{
"RfNo": "503",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "AF"
}
]
```

expected json,

```
[
{
"RfNo": "500",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "AF"
},
{
"RfNo": "502",
"ABaseFare": "110",
"ATax": "267.22",
"YBaseFare": "0",
"AirCode": "DD"
}
]
```

Comment: Do you sample data and the expected output for the same?

Comment: please check now @MBB

Answer (score 1):

Assume **obj** as the *array object*.

Function to group the object

```
const groupByKey = (list: any[], key: string, {omitKey = false}: { omitKey: true; }) => list.reduce((hash, {[key]: value, ...rest}) => ({
...hash, [value]: (hash[value] || []).concat(omitKey ? {...rest} : {...rest})
}), {});

const groupByKey1 = groupByKey(obj, 'AirCode', {omitKey: true});

const x: any[] = [];
Object.entries(groupByKey1).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => x.push(value)
);
const z: { ABaseFare: any; ATax: any; RfNo: any; YBaseFare: any; }[] = [];
x.forEach(value => {
  const p = {
    ABaseFare: value[0].ABaseFare,
    ATax: value[0].ATax,
    RfNo: value[0].RfNo,
    YBaseFare: value[0].YBaseFare,
   };
 z.push(p);
});
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same *filtering* as you. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68542911/8357634) worked (thanks!), however neither I nor you need the grouping at all. I found a less complex and faster solution for our use case:

```
this.faresData.reduce((r, a) => r.some(x => x.AirCode == a.AirCode) ? r : [...r, a], []);
```

I use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to "push" each 1st *fare* in the `else` case. The result contains exactly your expected json:

```
[
 {
  "RfNo": "500",
  "ABaseFare": "110",
  "ATax": "267.22",
  "YBaseFare": "0",
  "AirCode": "AF"
 },
 {
  "RfNo": "502",
  "ABaseFare": "110",
  "ATax": "267.22",
  "YBaseFare": "0",
  "AirCode": "DD"
 }
]
```